# React JS Quill editor with tables

Tags: reactjs, quill

in my react web app i am using **react-quill**  package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-quill version **1.3.3** which uses **Quill version 1.3.7** according to package-lock.json

By default, Quill editor doesn't support inserting/pasting nor creating tables. So I googled and found some npm packages which enables it.
Unfortunately, both *quill-table-ui* and *quill-better-table* requires Quill version 2.0.

I also found *quill-table* https://www.npmjs.com/package/quill-table but I wasn't able to make it work. I put code from Usage part to componentDidMount or inside render method and also set `table:true` in modules but it didn't work or either threw and errors.

**Is there any way how to enable tables in Quill 1.3 ?**

Afaik: Quill v2.0.0 still isn't officially released for prod and it doesnt support IE 11 only Edge, so these are the reasons I cannot upgrade.